# How to calculate arithmetic mean in listbox with numbers in it c#

Tags: c#, winforms

OK so... I have a program that calculates K/D or K/D/A (Kills to death ratio + with assists) and the results goes to the listbox where i want to do arithmetic mean on results in the listbox. I know how to do arithmetic mean but, I need to know how to get all the items(numbers) to sum up and spit it out into random double value or something so i can divide it by Listbox1.Items.Count();
Thank you.

Comment: So do you need to sum up all values of listbox? Or you want to add the numbers before being added to the listbox?

Comment: sum up all values of listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will sum up all values of the listbox:

```
        decimal sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToDecimal(listBox1.Items[i]);
        }
```

Add this code to the suitable event. If you want to perform sum on button click add this code to the button's click event.

You can look up to this link for a detailed instruction-[Sum of listbox items](https://www.csharp-console-examples.com/loop/for-loop/c-get-the-sum-of-the-items-in-a-listbox/)